# flutter web JS function call JS function from external JS library

Tags: javascript, flutter, web

I am going to build the JS function which calls external JS library.

```
// import external library
import pica from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pica@9.0.1/dist/pica.min.js';

function resize(param) {
    var src = param["src"];
    var toWidth = param["toWidth"];    
    //var callback = param["callback"];
    
    // call function in external library
    return pica.resizeBuffer({
        src: src,
        toWidth: toWidth,

    });
}
```

error : can't find pica
How can I use the JS function from external JS library?